# terra cotta lippage removal?

Tags: tile

We have some extremely uneven and ugly terra cotta tiles.  They're old, stained, and unevenly laid.  The grout is pitted and poorly done.

I'm wondering if there's a way to perform the lippage removal on these tiles, and just grind the hell out of this stuff?  I don't see much video coverage on it..

Answer (score 1):

sorry, but you are out of luck.  terrazzo is an homogenous material, and can thus be ground.  terra cotta is heterogenous, and cannot.  if you cut a terra cotta tile in half, you will find a thin layer of glazed vitreous oxide material at the top, and then unglazed parent substrate below that.  if you grind the tiles, you will remove the glaze in a random way (terra cotta by its very nature is a very warped, uneven material, with differing surface finishes and depth of glazing).  this will result in a spotty floor that is now as porous as a sponge, and not a lot harder than brick mortar.  not a good choice for a flooring material.

rip it up or lay new tile over it.

Answer (score 0):

If you rent a terrazzo floor grinder I guess you could probably grind them either down (smooth, flat, unstained) or off completely. I have no idea how that would play on a cost, work or time basis .vs. removal.

I doubt it will improve the grout joints much.

You can find a few videos if you use terrazzo in your search. They won't be grinding tile, most likely, but the machines should do it if anything will. Whether you can find one to rent would be the next hurdle.